# What is the meaning of "idiot-proof"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of "*idiot-proof*", as in:

> Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to
>   build bigger and better **idiot-proof** programs, and the Universe trying
>   to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the Universe is winning.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiot_proof

Comment: Look up the adjective [*proof*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/proof?q=proof). I think this is General Reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It describes programs that anyone can operate and that no one can damage, not even idiots.

Answer (score 1):

It means programs that are so easy to use that even an [idiot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiot) (someone with a very, very low IQ, maybe < 30) cannot use it incorrectly. This, of course, is contrary to [Murphy's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law), so it'll never happen, which is what "So far, the Universe is winning" means.